# Hiding the navigation buttons on Android using NativeScript

Tags: javascript, android, angular, nativescript

I am using Angular NativeScript, the application should be displayed on full screen without the navigation buttons bar ('back', 'home', and "all opened applications").
The buttons will be displayed when swiping down from the top of the screen.

I didn't find information in the NativeScript documentaion or anywhere else.

I've attached a picture of the navigation buttons for reference:

[image: android navigation buttons]

Comment: Try for full-screen mode

Comment: @khalid3e, you can move your comment to a proper answer to the question, and it would probably be accepted and get you more upvotes...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not advanced in NativeScript, but there is something called Immersive Mode in Android, I think it is the right term you should be searching for. See: https://rynop.com/2019/01/22/go-fullscreen-on-android-in-nativescript-angular/

*This was originally a comment but as @Shahar recommendation I moved it to the answers section...*